# Why is this question still on hold?

Tags: support, on-hold

I had asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41265441/how-can-i-debug-this-basic-do-while-statement) a few days ago and it was kept on hold for not following 'MCVE' and for being 'off topic' and that is reasonable. Afterward, I had a chat with a moderator and worked with him to fix the issues. I see no problem in the question anymore.

The point of this question is not to accuse anyone and neither is my purpose to remove the question from the 'on hold' list.

What I want to know is, what will others with a question on hold be forced to do in the same scenario? If they have corrected the mistake but the question is still on hold. What if it is a question they cannot solve without the community's help? What if it is something they need urgently?

Of course, they can have a question like this to remove their question from the on hold list. But isn't that tad inconvenient?

Comment: If they need something urgently, they shouldn't be asking for help on a site  with content provided by volunteers.  Also, Jonathan Leffler isn't a moderator; they're a regular user.  Moderators have ♦s next to their username

Comment: It didn't survive the [reopen queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/14669902).

Answer (score 20):

IMO, your question now does have a MCVE, but I will still not vote to reopen because it's a typo.

If I have understood the question correctly, you're asking why the time being printed is always the same.

That will always be the same, as you're initializing the variable `time` with 10. You're never changing that so it will always be the same.

Although, you are incrementing the variable `counter` which was initialized to 0. So, you're using the **wrong variable**. You need to print the variable `counter`, but instead you're printing the variable `time` which you're never changing in your program.

As this is a silly mistake, this won't be useful to future visitors, and thus I will opt for letting it be closed.